# How to pause and resume a gcp scheduler from a gcp function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-instances

I have been trying to pause a cloud scheduler if a condition is true and this all can be done in a function using Python only.
So, is it possible? Please help me

Comment: Please always try something on your own. Do not expect someone will always do your job for free while you don't try anything. I'm downvoting this post since it seems more a "someone do my job" than actually asking something

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that someone right my code. I'm a beginner in the cloud world and I didn't find something helpful so that's why i posted. if you think I posted intentionally that someone write my code. Then THANK YOU  for downvoting this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudscheduler/latest/google.cloud.scheduler_v1.services.cloud_scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient#google_cloud_scheduler_v1_services_cloud_scheduler_CloudSchedulerClient_pause_job) you have examples for pausing and resuming jobs.

For Pausing:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

def sample_pause_job():
    # Create a client
    client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = scheduler_v1.PauseJobRequest(
        name="name_value",
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.pause_job(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

For resuming:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

def sample_resume_job():
    # Create a client
    client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = scheduler_v1.ResumeJobRequest(
        name="name_value",
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.resume_job(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

Comment: Nice from you sharing your knowledge but helping people that does not show any effort and expects someone write their code never is a good idea (even if it is from the samples). Always try to make the OP at least put some effort